# Can't use array as an reference SnortSnarf HTMLMemStorage

Tags: perl, snort

I'm trying to install SnortSnarf and I'm getting the following error on Ubuntu, next to the terminal is the HTMLMemStorage.pm file. [image: snarf]

I've tried playing around with Line 290 but none of it worked and there doesn't seem to be any solutions I could find online about this. I've tried https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-security-4/snortsnard-generation-problem-111708/ and [CGI error Can't use an array as a reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51950005/cgi-error-cant-use-an-array-as-a-reference) but it's not deprecated so I'm not sure how to go from here.

Comment: Don't (just) post code and message as images.

Comment: This is an instance where `use strict` would have noticed that you used a variable that you had not declared. You have `$arr` but used `@arr`.

Comment: @ikegami What do you want me to do? It's the program itself that I haven't modified. Wouldn't a screenshot share the same purpose as posting the code itself?

Comment: @briandfoy Thank you, there were quite a few instances were this was the case for some reason which is kind of weird since I'd assume it wouldn't be in the release itself. Thanks.

Comment: Post it as text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The left-hand side of `->` must be an expression that returns a reference.

I think you want

```
$arr->[...]
```